# iOS detect WiFi hotspots or Bluetooth Devices

Tags: iphone, ios4, wifi

I know that without users permission trying to switch on WiFi or Bluetooth is not possible (rather comes under private API). I dont want to go there.

Assuming WiFi is switched on or assuming bluetooth is switched on. Is it possible to detect all Wifi hotspots around my device (iPhone or iPad)? Same for Bluetooth?

I want to do this in Xcode Version 4.x with iOS SDK 4.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**
Apple has deprecated a large part of the GameKit peering methods in iOS7. Added updated information for iOS8.

**iOS7 and earlier - GameKit/Wi-Fi;**
The [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008303) documentation contains all the information required to set up a peering mechanism using bluetooth The [GKPeerPickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKPeerPickerController) is the most important part for peering.

For peering using Wi-Fi; Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) example uses such a mechanism

**iOS8**
In iOS8 Apple has introduced the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328). Using this you can start using peering for Wi-Fi, bluetooth and other available services more easily. For starters you can use the [MCNearbyServiceBrowserClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MCNearbyServiceBrowser) to search for nearby devices and invite users a peer-to-peer session.

Comment: First two links are broken.