# iOS detect WiFi hotspots or Bluetooth Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS detect WiFi hotspots or Bluetooth Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162093/ios-detect-wifi-hotspots-or-bluetooth-devices)

I know that without users permission trying to switch on WiFi or Bluetooth is not possible (rather comes under private API). I dont want to go there.

Assuming WiFi is switched on or assuming bluetooth is switched on. Is it possible to detect all Wifi hotspots around my device (iPhone or iPad)? Same for Bluetooth?

I want to do this in Xcode Version 4.x with iOS SDK 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the question this is a potential duplicate of doesn't really provide an adequate answer in my mind, so here we go...

iOS has very limited WiFi options available to developers. What you **can** get: the current hotspot SSID and some other relevant data using `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo`. What you **can't** get: information about other access points that you may be in range of.

(...you can get this data through a private API call, but then your app won't make it on the app store).

Bluetooth is also fairly limited, but the question Deepak linked to you above actually provides more relevant information on that front.